# How to remove docker container even if root filesystem does not exists?

Tags: docker

I have one container that is `dead`, but I can't remove it, as you can see below.

How can I remove it? Or how can I clean my system manually to remove it?

```
:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
78b0dcaffa89        ubuntu:latest       "bash -c 'while tr..."   30 hours ago        Dead                                    leo.1.bkbjt6w08vgeo39rt1nmi7ock

:~$ docker rm --force 78b0dcaffa89
Error response from daemon: driver "aufs" failed to remove root filesystem for 78b0dcaffa89ac1e532748d44c9b2f57b940def0e34f1f0d26bf7ea1a10c222b: no such file or directory
```

Comment: you can try: `docker ps --filter "status=Dead" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm -f`

Comment: @Edwin As you can see I tried to remove with force argument, but it gives me this error.

Comment: ok, I thought is a problem with the container id, the printent output says something like `78b0dcaffa89ac1e532748d44c9b2f57b940def0e34f1f0d26bf7ea1a10c222b`. Have you tried to restart docker ?

Comment: That is the full container id, I think so.

Comment: A reboot surely can resolve the dead container issue, and most people reported that the container got removed from the `docker ps` list after they force removed it.

Comment: Does `/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/78b0dcaffa89ac1e532748d44c9b2f57b940def0e34f1f0d26bf7ea1a10c222b` actually exist? If it does, `umount` it.

Comment: No, it doesn't, in fact there is nothing with this name on `/var/lib/docker`. When I run this command `:~$ sudo find /var/lib/docker -name "78b0dcaffa89ac1e532748d44c9b2f57b94‌​0def0e34f1f0d26bf7ea‌​1a10c222b"` it does not show me anything.

Comment: Have you tried `docker rm -f -v 78b0dcaffa89`? (`-v` is for the volume)

Comment: Yes, I tried all parameters available on `docker rm`, nothing worked.

Comment: Try restarting docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message states, docker was configured to use `AUFS` as storage driver, but they recommend to use `Overlay2` instead, as you can read on this link:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21704#issuecomment-312934372

So I changed my configuration to use `Overlay2` as docker storage driver. When we do that it removes EVERYTHING from old storage drive, it means that my "Dead" container was gone also.

It is not exactly a solution for my original question, but the result was accomplished.

Answer (score 8):

Its possible Docker needs to be restarted.

I just ran into the same error message when trying to remove a container, and restarting Docker helped.

I'm running Version 17.12.0-ce-mac49 (21995)

To restart Docker, go to "Preferences" and click on the little bomb in the upper right hand corner.

In my situation I have Docker running off of a expansion drive on my MacBook.  After coming out of sleep mode, the expansion drive was automatically ejected (undesirable).  But after mounting the drive again, I realized Docker needed to be restarted in order to initialize everything again.  At this point I was able to remove containers (docker rm  -f).

Maybe its not the same situation, but restarting Docker is a useful thing to try.

Comment: Kinda not always an option on a production server.

Answer (score 2):

While browsing related issues, I found something similar ["Driver aufs failed to remove root filesystem", "device or resource busy"](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9665), and at around 80% below, there was a solution which said to use `docker stop cadvisor`; then `docker rm [dead container]`

Edit 1: docker stop **cadvisor** instead of docker stop **deadContainerId**

Comment: Thanks, but still does not works. I search for similar issues also, but I couldn't find any workaround, or manual steps to remove it.

Comment: @Azize I misunderstood what was written about cadvisor and replaced it with deadContainerId. Please see if this works. And Some people were talking about using umount at https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9665#issuecomment-168005655

Comment: In this link `cadvisor` is the container name. We can remove container from its name or from its Id. I tried both, the result is the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share how I got here. My disk on the host was getting full while working with docker containers, ended up getting `failed to remove root filesystem` myself as well. Burned some time before I realized that my disk is full, and then also after freeing up some space, with trying to restart docker. Nothing worked, only closing everything and rebooting the machine. I hope you'll save some time.